# Google Accompanist FlowLayout library breaks Compose (Cannot access class 'InteractionState')

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-accompanist

I have the following Compose dependencies, where `$compose_version` is 1.0.0-alpha12:
[image]

This builds fine. However, the second I try to build this project after adding a `com.google.accompanist:accompanist-flowlayout:0.19.0` dependency, I see this error in quite a few places in my project:
[image]
The case always seems to be with various composables, which accept the `onClick` argument: `Button`, `BottomNavigationItem` and `DropDownMenuItem`. I mean, every single one of them has an `InteractionState` argument alongside `onClick`.

I've tried multiple versions of `accompanist-flowlayout` down to 15 with no result. But I didn't experiment with other Compose dependencies versions because I inherited this project and a lot of things break when I do so.

How do i fix it?

Comment: Accompanist depends on the current stable version of compose, as of now this is 1.0.3. Upgrade your other dependencies accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you simply need to update your Jetpack Compose version.

As specified in the [repo's](https://github.com/google/accompanist) information :

> Each [release](https://github.com/google/accompanist/releases) outlines what version of the Compose libraries it depends on.

You are using Accompanist `0.19.0`, and the compose version is specified in the [changelog](https://github.com/google/accompanist/releases/tag/v0.19.0)

> Update to Compose 1.0.3 and bump other dependencies up (#748) @manuelvicnt